# AutoIt - Compare PixelCheckSum with Image

Tags: autoit

How can I do something like this?

```
 global $k = 0

   Local $aCheckSum = PixelChecksum(490, 660, 630, 690)

   While $k = 0 
      Sleep(100)
      If $aCheckSum = Image.png Then ; HOW CAN I DO THIS COMPARISON????
         $k = 1
         Send("{ENTER}")
      EndIf
   WEnd
```

Thanks to all answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [ImageSearch](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/) UDF.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past. (Of course the ImageSearch UDF might work better) but You can compare a serial of pixel from fixed position into both Image and compare those selected Piexels.
In my case I used a kind of 20ish randomly placed pixel, applying the same scheme on the second image and go the result quite easily.

Let me know if that's help or if you need the code extract...

Vlu.